# accessing phpmyadmin as root

Tags: server-setup

Im trying to access phpmyadmin on my server as the user root. I type root as the username and blank as the password and its not letting me in. I setup phpmyadmin.conf to only allow access from my IP address, and here is the config.inc.php:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

I also tried setting auth_type as config, changed the host to my IP Address, and added at one point the following:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Im not quite sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First revert all changes in file you made, you have to simply reset mysql root password for that. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html) for resetting mysql root password .